# How to bind Xtended WPF Toolkit Wizard's CurrentPage in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wizard, wpftoolkit

I've built a wizard of several pages using [Xceed WPF Toolkit's Wizard Control](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/Wizard), and I need the program to know what page is currently active, in order to be able to determine the necessary steps.

I'm trying to bind `CurrentPage` to the ViewModel, as follows:

**XAML:**

```
<xctk:Wizard CurrentPage="{Binding CurrentStep, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <xctk:WizardPage Name="Import">
       ...
    </xctk:WizardPage>
       ...
</xctk:Wizard>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public WizardPage CurrentStep { get; set; }
```

The problem is that `CurrentStep` always returns `Null` and the wizard just shows a blank page.

What needs to be done in order to have `CurrentPage` return the active wizard page using MVVM?

Answer (score 2):

CurrentStep should be a DependencyProperty or ViewModel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged, otherwise binding will not work.

Answer (score 1):

xaml:

```
<xctk:Wizard    x:Name="wizMain"
                Grid.Row="1"
                FinishButtonClosesWindow="True" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding wizardPages}" 
                Background="White"
                ExteriorPanelMinWidth="100"
                HelpButtonVisibility="Hidden"
                CanSelectNextPage="{Binding CanProceed, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                CurrentPage="{Binding Path=CurrentWizardPage, Mode=TwoWay}"
>
```

from the ViewModel:

```
public WizardPage CurrentWizardPage { get; set; }
```

HTH,
Ray